# Parse Android: update ParseObject containing an array of ParseUsers throws UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError

Tags: parse-platform

im working on an Android App.

I have a custom class which has relations with TWO ParseUsers and other fields. As suggested by the docs, I used an array (with key "usersArray") to store the pointers for the two ParseUsers, because I want to be able to use "include" to include the users when i query my custom class. I can create a new object and save it successfully.

```
//My custom parse class:
CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();
ArrayList<ParseUser> users = new ArrayList<ParseUser>();
users.add(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
users.add(anotherUser);
customObject.put("usersArray", users);
//I also store other variable which i would like to update later
customObject.put("otherVariable",false); 
customObject.saveInBackground();
```

Also, i can query successfully with:

```
ParseQuery<CustomObject> query = CustomObject.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("usersArray", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
query.whereEqualTo("usersArray", anotherUser);
query.include("usersArray");
query.findInBackground( .... );
```

My problem is when trying to UPDATE one of those CustomObject.
So after retrieving the CustomObject with the previous query, if I try to change the value of the "otherVariable" to true and save the object, I am getting a `UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError` or `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated` exceptions.

```
CustomObject customObject = customObject.get(0); //From the query
customObject.put("otherVariable", true);
customObject.saveInBackground(); // EXCEPTION
```

I can see this is somehow related to the fact im trying to update an object which contains a pointer to a ParseUser. But im NOT modifying the user, i just want to update one of the fields of the CustomObject.

¿There is any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late but Parse users have ACL of public read and private write so you should do `users.isAuthenticated()` to check if its true or false.

If false then login with the user and retry. **Note:** you cannot edit info on two users at the same time without logging out and relogging in.

Another thing you can do is use Roles and define an admin role by using ACL which can write over all users.

Comment: What's the easiest way to go around this without using Roles? I already have a column names "accountType" and I have an "admin" and "regular" values.